# Jersey REST service to return both jpeg and png images

Tags: java, image, rest, jersey

I am trying to have a single Jersey REST service that could return an image of either a jpeg type or a png type , the reason is because the service only has access to and is returning binary data and cannot tell if its a jpeg image or a png image .

If I use the following declaration the browser displays binary data .

```
@Produces("image/*")
```

However if I use the following for jpeg images the correct image is displayed.

```
@Produces("image/jpeg").
```

I want to know how I could use a single declaration that would make the browser identify the right type of image(jpeg or png) to be rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the service doesn't know the type, it cannot be any more specific than `image/*`. But, you could inspect the first few bytes of the data to [detect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) the type and add `Content-Type` header accordingly.

Note that the purpose for having more than one @Produces annotation is for content negotiation, where the user agent express the wanted resource representation and the server answers with an appropriate variant of the data, e.g. JPEG *or* PNG.

Comment: if I am able to identify the content type how do I set/add the Content-Type header?

Comment: You use the type() method on the ResponseBuilder

Comment: @forty-two I think that's the best way, no need to even specify Produces in that case.

Answer (score 6):

According to JAX-RS specification it is allowed to list multiple media types:

```
@Produces({"image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"})
```

see: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html

**Update:**
for more details see @forty-two 's answer too.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help when you don't know what you are producing.

Comment: i'm not sure this is a relevant issue in this particular case.

Comment: Not relevant? How does that declaration help the client to identify the media type?

Comment: Container determines and produces valid "Content-Type" HTTP header + "Content-Length". This is enough information for client.

Comment: The container cannot decide! When you have a single @Produces annotation you can leave it for the container to set the content type, otherwise you have to do it. Read the second paragraph of the link you provided in the answer.

Comment: How come it always worked for me automatically? Container is capable to determine valid content types from binary data structure when returning images from the method.

Comment: My guess is that it's the browser that is smart, not the container.

Comment: +1ed your answer, you are right, browser is determining correct mime type. From JAX-RS first mime type is being used automatically when there are multiple mime types provided in @Produces annotation.